# How to install missing libraries in IPv6 Linux machine, yum is not working here

Tags: linux, ipv6

How to install linux libraries in ipv6 machine, yum is not working for me in ipv6 setup.

e.g.

```
yum install pam.i686
```

is simply not working.

Is there any convenient way like `yum` which we can use in ipv6 as well.

Comment: what is your install result or log for `yum` under ipv6? what is your `yum` and os version, what is your firewall setting? ipv4 works?

Comment: Please add some clarifications: which distribution is this? Please be explicit about the network connectivity you have: if this an IPv6-only setup?

Comment: Hello, it pure IPv6 setup, RHEL distribution. In my ipv4 setups 'yum' is working fine for me.

Comment: Error downloading packages:
  libstdc++-4.8.2-16.2.el7_0.i686: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  zlib-1.2.7-13.el7.i686: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  cracklib-2.9.0-11.el7.i686: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  xz-libs-5.1.2-8alpha.el7.i686: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  nss-softokn-freebl-3.16.2-1.el7_0.i686: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  glibc-2.17-55.el7_0.1.i686: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  pam-1.1.8-9.el7.i686: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

----getting this kind of errors, at the same time in ip4 machines its working fine for me.

Comment: In that case it's Redhat's fault for not providing their download services over IPv6. You should complain to their support department. These days important services like this should be available over both IPv4 and IPv6.

Answer (score -1):

For Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install libice6 libsm6 libxt6 libxrender1 libfontconfig1 libcups2

For SUSE: sudo zypper install xorg-x11-libICE xorg-x11-libSM xorg-x11-libXrender xorg-x11-libXext fontconfig cups-libs

For RedHat: sudo yum install libXrender libSM libICE libXext fontconfig cups-libs

for more info please check the link http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/install-lolibfiles.html